# How to print the contents of RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm attempting to print the contents of a collection to the Spark console.

I have a type:

```
linesWithSessionId: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = FilteredRDD[3]
```

And I use the command:

```
scala> linesWithSessionId.map(line => println(line))
```

But this is printed :

> res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Unit] = MappedRDD[4] at map at :19

How can I write the RDD to console or save it to disk so I can view its contents?

Comment: Hi! did you read the comments on the answer, accepted by you? It appears to be misleading

Comment: @dk14 agreed, I've reassigned accepted answer

Comment: RDD are being relegated as second class citizens, you should use DataFrame and the ``show`` method.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

If you want to view the content of a RDD, one way is to use `collect()`:

```
myRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

That's not a good idea, though, when the RDD has billions of lines. Use `take()` to take just a few to print out:

```
myRDD.take(n).foreach(println)
```

Comment: if i use foreach on RDD ( which has millions of lines) to write the content into HDFS as single file, will it work without any issues on cluster?

Comment: The reason i am not using `saveAsTextFile` on RDD is , i need to write the RDD content into more than one file, that's why i am using `foreach`

Comment: If you want to save in a single file, you can coalesce you RDD into one partition before calling saveAsTextFile, but again this may cause issues. I think the best option is to write in multiple files in HDFS, then use hdfs dfs --getmerge in order to merge the files

Comment: you said that when use foreach on an RDD it will persist it into the driver's RAM, is the Statement correct? because what i understood is foreach will run on each worker[cluster] not on driver.

Comment: saveAsTextFile will write one file per partition, which is what you want (multiple files). Otherwise as Oussama suggests, you can do rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile() to get one file. If the RDD has too few partitions for your liking, you can try rdd.repartition(N).saveAsTextFile()

Comment: @Oussama One question. How can we print an `RDD` of type `Array[String]`? When I try the manner above, I just get memory addresses. Is there an `toString()` functionality?

Comment: @Brian , you can use whatever function instead of println, you won't have any serialization problems since since you use take(n). Therefore you can create your own printing function and put it instead of println

Comment: `take` doesn't seem to work for me. I think it's sorting the results, which is not what I want (for a start, I have a `scala.Tuple2` which does not implement `Comparable`) is there a way to just take some results as fast as possible but not care which?

Comment: You could also add this link to official doc: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#printing-elements-of-an-rdd

Answer (score 50):

The `map` function is a [*transformation*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations), which means that Spark will not actually evaluate your RDD until you run an [*action*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) on it.

To print it, you can use `foreach` (which is an action):

```
linesWithSessionId.foreach(println)
```

To write it to disk you can use one of the `saveAs...` functions (still actions) from the [RDD API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/core/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)

Comment: Maybe you need to mention `collect` so that the RDD can be printed in the console.

Comment: `foreach` itself will first "materialize" the RDD and then run `println` on each element, so `collect` is not really needed here (although you can use it, of course)...

Comment: Actually without collect(), before foreach, I'm not able to see anything on console.

Comment: On Spark 1.2.0 this does not print the RDD. @Oussama's answer does work, however.

Comment: Actually it works totally fine in my Spark shell, even in 1.2.0. But I think I know where this confusion comes from: the original question asked how to print an RDD to the Spark console (= shell) so I assumed he would run a local job, in which case `foreach` works fine. If you are running a job on a cluster and you want to print your rdd then you should `collect` (as pointed out by other comments and answers) so that it is sent to the driver before `println` is executed. And using `take` as suggested by Oussama might be a good idea if your RDD is too big.

Comment: The above answer is bad. You should unaccept it. Foreach will not print to the console, it will print on your worker nodes. If you have only one node then foreach will work. But if you have only one node, then why are you using spark? Just use SQL awk, or Grep, or something much simpler. So I think the only valid answer is collect. If collect is to big for you and you only want a sample use take or head or simillar functions as described below.

Answer (score 16):

You can convert your `RDD` to a `DataFrame` then `show()` it.

```
// For implicit conversion from RDD to DataFrame
import spark.implicits._

fruits = sc.parallelize([("apple", 1), ("banana", 2), ("orange", 17)])

// convert to DF then show it
fruits.toDF().show()
```

This will show the top 20 lines of your data, so the size of your data should not be an issue.

```
+------+---+                                                                    
|    _1| _2|
+------+---+
| apple|  1|
|banana|  2|
|orange| 17|
+------+---+
```

Comment: I think it is `import spark.implicits._`

Comment: What is the library was used here? I can't detect neither `toDF` nor `spark.implicits._` in spark scope.

Answer (score 13):

If you're running this on a cluster then `println` won't print back to your context. You need to bring the `RDD` data to your session. To do this you can force it to local array and then print it out:

```
linesWithSessionId.toArray().foreach(line => println(line))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c.take(10)
```

and Spark newer version will show table nicely.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many architectural differences between `myRDD.foreach(println)` and `myRDD.collect().foreach(println)` (not only 'collect', but also other actions). One the differences I saw is when doing `myRDD.foreach(println)`, the output will be in a random order. For ex: if my rdd is coming from a text file where each line has a number, the output will have a different order. But when I did `myRDD.collect().foreach(println)`, order remains just like the text file.

Answer (score 1):

In python

```
   linesWithSessionIdCollect = linesWithSessionId.collect()
   linesWithSessionIdCollect
```

This will printout all the contents of the RDD

Comment: Thanks but I tagged this question with scala not python

Answer (score 1):

Instead of typing each time, you can;

[1] Create a generic print method inside Spark Shell.

```
def p(rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]) = rdd.foreach(println)
```

[2] Or even better, using implicits, you can add the function to RDD class to print its contents.

```
implicit class Printer(rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]) {
    def print = rdd.foreach(println)
}
```

Example usage:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4)).map(_*2)

p(rdd) // 1
rdd.print // 2
```

Output:

```
2
6
4
8
```

**Important**

This only makes sense if you are working in local mode and with a small amount of data set. Otherwise, you either will not be able to see the results on the client or run out of memory because of the big dataset result.

Answer (score 0):

You can also save as a file: `rdd.saveAsTextFile("alicia.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

In java syntax:

```
rdd.collect().forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
```