# Printing spark command in yarn and cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I need to print some commands in spark yarn mode. Obviously println(message) doesn't work... I want to find a way to collect the message. Can someone point me to the current method for example using collect?

How to use collect?

Does the below code work?

```
val c=message.collect()
println (c)
```

Comment: already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23173811/2784721

Comment: @amit_kumar that answer isn't not correct a highly over-voted. It's been downvoted 6 times for a reason. Nevertheless, for the OP, Please read on how to ask questions on SO. This question a very low quality !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the below command:

```
message.foreach(println)
```

You will find output of above call in executor logs.