# Printing values in map function on the console in yarn deployment mode

Tags: apache-spark

I developed a streaming application, the application have a map function such as bellow:

```
probeFileLines.map(x => { println(x._2.toString().take(1)); x._2.toString()})
```

I need to print x._.2 on my console in the driver program...so I used take method but it doesn't show anything on the console..I am running my application on yarn -client mode..there are some [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23173811/2784721) addressing how to do this for a RDD but my problem is something different..

Comment: you are missing action function at the end. Spark transformations are lazy and do not do anything until action is called. Solutions provided below suggest making use of print or collet; both action function to make your map code to run. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be able to use Spark Streaming's `print()` [function?](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream@print(num:Int):Unit)

```
val numberToPrint = 10;
probeFileLines
  .map(x => {
    x._2.toString()
  })
  .print(numberToPrint);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to following approach:

```
val inputRDDV2 = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))
val inputRDDV2Map = inputRDDV2.map(num=>num*2).collect()
println("Applying map() to new RDD: ========================> ")
inputRDDV2Map.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`collect`** method over RDD to get all elements of RDD as an array at driver program. Once you get array using the **`collect`** method, you can print element of array by iterating over it.